Is it possible to write math formula using markdoc?
I'm using the tailwind syntax template to take class notes and need to write math formula such as y_i = e(x_i) ≡ x_i + s_i mod 2 with y_i meaning y subscript i.
Regular markdown enclose math formula with $, it does not work for markdoc (I've tried enclosing it with $$ and that does not work either).
markdoc is used throughout the site to generate table of contents and such, so I can't use another markdown package.
Have any of you find a way to write math formula using markdoc ?

One way that worked for me is to use HTML entities or Unicode characters. But this would probably only work for simple formulas, unfortunately. Your formula for example would be: &#121;<sub>i</sub> = e(&#120;<sub>i</sub>) &#x2261; &#120;<sub>i</sub> + &#115;<sub>i</sub> mod 2 

Thank you for taking the time to answer. I have too many formulas to write using unicode, that'd take ages. I'm afraid I won't be able to use the template :/ Thank you anyway

I've found a way to display math formula using the tailwind syntax template:

Install the following packages: react-markdown, rehype-katex, remark-math
In src/components, create a file MathFormula (or whatever suits you) with the following code:

import 'katex/dist/katex.min.css'

import Markdown from 'react-markdown'
import rehypeKatex from 'rehype-katex'
import remarkMath from 'remark-math'

export function MathFormula({ formula }: { formula: string }) {
  return (
    <Markdown remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]} rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}>
      {formula}
    </Markdown>
  )
}



Add the following entry in src/markdoc/tags.js:

mathFormula: {
  attributes: {
    formula: { type: String },
  },
  render: MathFormula,
},


In you md file, you can now use: {% mathFormula formula="$d_k(y) = x ≡ a^1 * (y - b) mod 26$" /%} 

The formula will be properly displayed
